# XML file not well-formed - Extra content at the end of the document

Tags: xml

With this small XML file I get the error (notepad++ - plugin "XML Tools"):

```
XML Parsing error at line 5:
Extra content at the end of the document
```

The document looks like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fields>
    <var10DInterestRisk>
        <1439769600>17.17</1439769600>
        <1444003200>16.58</1444003200>
        <1440979200>18.4</1440979200>
        <1437955200>16.69</1437955200>
        <1442188800>17.48</1442188800>
        <1439164800>16.02</1439164800>
        <1443398400>18.7</1443398400>
        <1440374400>18.26</1440374400>
        <1437350400>17.22</1437350400>
        <1441584000>16.16</1441584000>
        <1438560000>15.35</1438560000>
        <1442793600>19.21</1442793600>
    </var10DInterestRisk>
    <gamma>0.053588957997224</gamma>
    <issuerProductType>MassIssuanceVanillaWarrant_Equity Warrant</issuerProductType>
    <lastTradingDate>2016-12-15</lastTradingDate>
</fields>
```

I can't find the reason why.. :/ Can you help me??

Thank you!!

Comment: I have no idea why you'd get *that* error, when I run that code through a lint I get `4: parser error : StartTag: invalid element name
        <1439769600>17.17</1439769600>`

Comment: When/where exactly do you get this error? (I know notepad++ only as an text editor so there should be no problem opening/editing this file)

Comment: BTW, if you wanted to make a minimal reproducer (or fix this yourself!), you'd start taking contents out of the file, and seeing when it *stopped* generating the same error. This would, by process of reduction, make it clear that it was the elements with numeric names that caused your problem.

Comment: @TobiMarg: I am using a plugin for Notepad++ called "XML Tools". There is a function "Check XML syntax now".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the element names cannot be numeric:

> Element names must start with a letter or underscore

Source: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_elements.asp

Comment: Entirely correct answer, but could you find a better source? (W3Schools is completely unassocated with the W3C, and often has inaccurate content).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Sure, I understand. I'm looking for it now.

Comment: The official / canonical source would be http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-Name; or, as described before that point: "[Definition: A Name is an Nmtoken with a restricted set of initial characters.] Disallowed initial characters for Names include digits, diacritics, the full stop and the hyphen."

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Yes, that's a better resource, thank you.